MODBUS on Linux
I am currently working on a project allowing 2 pressure sensors to communicate with a Raspberry Pi's Linux based operating system. This system has two differential pressure sensors connected to an Ethernet-Serial Server. This server is then connected to the raspberry pi via ethernet. I have already allowed successful communication with my Windows PC. I am now struggling trying to figure out how to allow successful communication with my Raspberry pi.
Here is my python script for my Linux operating system:
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
server_ip = "10.0.50.100"
server_port = 4660
server_port2 = 4661

client = ModbusTcpClient(server_ip, server_port)
client2 = ModbusTcpClient(server_ip, server_port2)

if not connection: 
    print("Unable to connect")
else: 
    print("Device successfully connected")

if not connection2:
    print("Unable to connect")
else:
    print("Second device successfully connected")

id = client.read_holding_registers(address=304, count=1, slave=1)
print("The ID for your pressure sensor is: " + str(id.registers[0]))

id2 = client.read_holding_registers(address=304, count=1, slave=2)
print("The ID for your pressure sensor is: " + str(id2.registers[0]))

The error that I am recieving is this:
Device successfully connected
Second Device successfully connected 
Attribute: 'ModbusIOException' object has no attribute 'registers'

I don't know what else to do to get this to work on my Linux based system.
I have attached the block diagram that shows the connections for all the devices that I am using.
I have tried various different things like installing the "puTTY" software which did not work. I have also tried writing multiple scripts but the one I stated above is the closest to working.

your call to read_holding_registers fails, and instead of a normal response returns a ModbusIOException. Also the code you posted is not working, connection is not defined.
Try starting with a single modbus device, and I think you need to call client.connect() before reading registers
